# Adding a column to a datatable in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to add a column to data I have imported (and will export) as a CSV.

I am importing a CSV:

[image]

What I want to do add another column, perhaps "10/15/22" when the process runs, and then update the values under that date.

In effect, the document will grow to the right, adding a column each time it is run.

I have an object called $test.  It will have values like:

```
$test.users = "7"
$test.SomeBSValue = "22"
$test.Computers = "52"
```

When all is said and done, my output should look like:
[image]

Adding to the list any values I have that are not part of the list already, but recording the values I have under the heading for the date.

So, if the script is run and collects 100 data points, those data point would all be in the CSV under the date.

I would have thought this would be easy, but now I am drawing a complete blank.

I've considered (but have not coded) even trying to put into a GUI grid view and then reading the data back and writing the CSV (but there should be an easier way, right?)

Comment: Why is your structure inverted? I would have the Settings,Users,Computers etc as headers and add a row for each date.

Comment: Your `test` "array" looks more like an object in your question and it's somewhat unclear if those are 3 sample row addtions that should be matched to exisisting row on name or not. If his is all data to be added to a new "10/15/22" column, it should be in a two-column csv: `"Settings","10/15/22"<crlf>"users",7<crlf>"SomeBSvalue",22`... Please clarify as to whether this is the case or otherwise....

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct that.. An object, not an array.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). There's no reason to post a csv file as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idea is pretty terrible idea, as you stated, "grow to the right" is definitely not a good approach and you should consider a better way of doing it, data should always expand vertically.

As for the solution, you can create new columns easily with [`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) and dynamically generated [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2).

**Note**, this should definitely not be considered an efficient approach. This **will be slow** because `Select-Object` is slow.

```
function Add-Column {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, DontShow, Mandatory)]
        [object] $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $ColumnName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $ReferenceProperty,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [hashtable] $Values
    )

    begin {
        $calculatedProp = @{ N = $ColumnName }
    }
    process {
        $calculatedProp['E'] = { 0 }
        if($value = $InputObject.$ReferenceProperty) {
            if($Values.ContainsKey($value)) {
                $calculatedProp['E'] = { $Values[$value] }
            }
        }
        $InputObject | Select-Object *, $calculatedProp
    }
}
```

- Usage

```
Import-Csv path\to\csv | Add-Column -ColumnName '09/15/22' -ReferenceProperty Settings -Values @{
    users       = "7"
    SomeBSValue = "22"
    Computers   = "52"
}
```

- Result

```
Settings    08/15/22 09/15/22
--------    -------- --------
Users       0        7
Computers   0        52
SomeValue1  0        0
SomeValue2  0        0
SomeValue3  0        0
Stat1       0        0
Stat2       7        0
Stat3       0        0
SomeBSValue 1        22
```

This function allows then pipe into `Export-Csv` at ease:

```
Import-Csv path\to\csv | Add-Column ... | Export-Csv path\to\newCsv
```

Comment: I don't have the option to grow vertically.  The data gets fed into another process I have no control over.
The one weakness here is if the new data has values that are not in the source CSV, then this won't add them (an easy enough problem to fix).

Comment: @J.DuBois I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't actually use it as a CSV we can treat it like regular content.

Say we have a file in C:\test called test.csv that looks as follows:

```
"Settings","08/15/22","09/15/22"
"Users",0,0
"Computers",0,1
"SomeValue1",0,2
"SomeValue2",0,2
"SomeValue3",0,2
"Stat1",0,10
"Stat2",7,0
"Stat3",0,0
"SomeBSValue",1,2
```

We can import it, add the row from the object to each corresponding row and right the file to test2.csv.

```
$test = @{
    Settings = "10/15/22"
    users = "7"
    Computers = "52"
    SomeValue1 = "22"
    SomeValue2 = "24"
    SomeValue3 = "25"
    Stat1 = "4"
    Stat2 = "3"
    Stat3 = "2"
    SomeBSValue = "1"
}

$content = Get-Content "C:\test\test.csv"
$newContent = @()
foreach($row in $content){
    foreach($key in $test.Keys){
        if($row -like "*$key*"){
            $row = $row + "," + $test."$key"
            $newContent += $row
        }
    }
}

$newContent | Out-File "C:\test\test2.csv"
```

After running the script it will have added the values from the object:

```
"Settings","08/15/22","09/15/22",10/15/22
"Users",0,0,7
"Computers",0,1,52
"SomeValue1",0,2,22
"SomeValue2",0,2,22
"SomeValue3",0,2,22
"Stat1",0,10,4
"Stat2",7,0,4
"Stat3",0,0,4
```

Edit:
If you want the date between quotes, replace `$row = $row + "," + $test."$key"` with this:

```
if($key -eq "Settings"){
    $row = $row + "," + '"' + $test."$key" + '"'
}else{
    $row = $row + "," + $test."$key"
}
```

Comment: There are still some caveats for instance if the object does not have all the fields from the file, you will have to make sure to add a "0" or null or whatever to indicate that there is no value for that row.